# Perl Regex Unexpected Performance Hit

Tags: regex, performance, perl, pcre

Perl v5.28.1

The benchmark :

```
use common::sense;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $UPPER = 10_000_000;
my $str = 'foo bar baz';

cmpthese(10, {
        'empty for-loop' => sub {
                        for my $i (1..$UPPER) {}
                },
        'regex match' => sub {
                        for my $i (1..$UPPER) {
                                $str =~ /foo/;
                        }
                },
        'regex match (single compile)' => sub {
                        my $re = qr/foo/;
                        for my $i (1..$UPPER) {
                                $str =~ $re;
                        }
                },
        'regex match (anchor)' => sub {
                        for my $i (1..$UPPER) {
                                $str =~ /^foo/;
                        }
                },
        'regex match (anchor) (single compile)' => sub {
                        my $re = qr/^foo/;
                        for my $i (1..$UPPER) {
                                $str =~ $re;
                        }
                },
});
```

The results :

```
                                      s/iter regex match (anchor) (single compile) regex match (single compile) regex match (anchor) regex match empty for-loop
regex match (anchor) (single compile)   3.83                                    --                         -21%                 -60%        -84%           -97%
regex match (single compile)            3.04                                   26%                           --                 -50%        -80%           -96%
regex match (anchor)                    1.53                                  151%                          99%                   --        -61%           -92%
regex match                            0.601                                  537%                         405%                 154%          --           -81%
empty for-loop                         0.117                                 3170%                        2496%                1205%        414%             --
```

Because foo happens to occur at the start of the string, I would expect adding an explicit anchor (^) to the regex to do nothing ... not halve performance !

As well, I've read something to the effect that Perl is smart enough to *not* recompile expressions with fixed strings, even when contained within loops.
But why would attempting to manually/explicitly "precompile" an expression into variable $re cause such a performance hit ?!

I changed the search substring "foo" to "asdf" (which does not occur in $str), and anchoring does let the engine drop out of searching sooner.
But assigning the expression into a variable is still a massive performance hit - much more than I would have expected ! :

```
                                         Rate regex match (single compile) regex match (anchor) (single compile) regex match regex match (anchor) empty for-loop
regex match (single compile)          0.401/s                           --                                  -10%        -79%                 -83%           -96%
regex match (anchor) (single compile) 0.447/s                          11%                                    --        -76%                 -81%           -95%
regex match                            1.88/s                         369%                                  321%          --                 -19%           -79%
regex match (anchor)                   2.33/s                         481%                                  421%         24%                   --           -75%
empty for-loop                         9.17/s                        2185%                                 1951%        387%                 294%             --
```

So 2 questions to summarize :
 - Why should a start-of-string anchor halve performance ?
 - Why should compiling an expression (qr//) into a variable be 80% slower than using the same expression in-line ?

Comment: Why are your lists showing different rows. They eye sees the code before the numbers, that is the reference. I started to correlate, but gave up.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by different rows ? 
The module "Benchmark" orders its output from slower -> faster for tabular comparison. Of course different benchmark conditions will result in differently-ordered lists, with no relation to the order in which I defined the anonymous subs in the code ?

Comment: "_Not sure what you mean different rows_" -- I'm not sure either, but your second output is _not_ from the shown program, so maybe that's what they meant?  More to the point, you say "_80% slower_" but I see the factor of five in the benchmark output (and I, too, get a factor of three) ... am I missing or misreading something?

Comment: @zdim Yes, the 2nd isn't from the program. Quote: 'I changed the search substring "foo" to "asdf" (which does not occur in $str)[...]'. If you scroll the 2nd output, you'll also see that Benchmark has quantified row 1 ("regex match (single compile)") as being a relative -79% as performant as its counterpart ("regex match"). Ditto for the anchored two (-81% on row 2, compare 2nd last column).

Comment: In the first output the "_regex match (single compile)_" has 3.04 s/iter while "_regex match_" has 0.601 s/iter; in the second output the rates are 0.4/s vs. 1.88/s.  That's factors around 5 (five) both ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the anchor was preventing a particular regex optimisation from occurring. This has been fixed in 5.30.0.

Using a qr// object currently incurs a slight penalty since internally part of the regex structure has to be copied (related to to the fact that each regex object has its own set of capture indices). Noone's thought of a good fix for this yet.

Comment: Hey, that's great insight thanks !  
I switched to v5.30.0 and indeed the regex with the ^ anchor is faster than both anchorless. My go-to thought is rarely, "Huh, must be a bug in Perl" !

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on any of this, or offer links?  A "_slight penalty_" for a `qr` object doesn't explain the factor of 3 (three) that OP shows this trailing behind an otherwise equal match (which I confirmed in my tests). Also, what kind of optimization helps anchoring a match for a pattern that _is_ always at the beginning of the string (what this tests, not failures)?

Comment: (it's actually a factor of 5 (five) they show. I get a factor of 3 with 5.16.3.  and with 5.29.2 close to 5x)

Comment: The trivial pattern /^foo/ is heavily optimised and doesn't even call the regex engine proper. With a heavyweight regex that takes real time to run, the overhead of cloning the regex each time becomes a small(er) part of the overall execution time

Comment: Would love to see this improved in future Perl releases !
Although to be fair ... I guess in cases as trivial as these, "improving" this discrepancy would be tantamount to premature optimization ... And I've yet to test how performance compares with more complex expressions, so the issue might be moot in "real" code.